Сбивается парсар синтаксиса в dbeaver
В dbeaver подсветка синтаксиса сбивается при некоторых обстоятельствах. Тема и темная и светлая ведут себя одинаково, расцветка не менялась - стоковая. БД Postgre, стоит на ubuntu.
Замечено при подзапросах в select и после ключевого слова ANY.
Подскажите как починить.
Для примера скрин с ANY. Если строку убрать, расцветка восстанавливается.
